# 404 Error with all links on Administer Page

Tags: wordpress, error

I just installed fresh CiviCRM 4.6.10 on Wordpress 4.4

Everything seems to be working fine and it looks like this crm is perfect for our needs but I am running into one problem-

If I go to Administer > Administration Console on the dropdown menu, every single link on that page brings me to a 404 not found error. EX: clicking on Organization and Contact info this is the URL I am getting a 404 not found http://(site)/civicrm/admin/domain?action=update&reset=1

But, if I go on the dropdown menu to Administer > Administration Console > Configuration Checklist and edit settings from links in there.. everything seems to be fine. URL for Organization Address and Contact Info is http://(site)/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fdomain&action=update&reset=1&civicrmDestination=%2Fwp-admin%2Fadmin.php%3Fpage%3DCiviCRM%26q%3Dcivicrm%2Fadmin%2Fconfigtask%26reset%3D1

Seems like something is wrong and the full URL isn't linked in the Administration Console?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The path in the links that give you a 404 are the paths where CiviCRM would be found by default if installed under Drupal.  The links that work are appropriate to Wordpress.

I can't think of any reason why this would happen in one place but not another - I just checked my Wordpress site and those links are correct.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but my problem is I cannot access the link provided in the answer given by William - it returns a 404 Page Not Found Error. Can anyone provide any advice on how to solve the issue? I feel I may have to change something in the database but I'm not sure what to change. I've had a look at the civicrm_domains table but I'm not sure what I can change there to make my links work, or if anything there needs to be changed. Thanks, Monica.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the base URL correctly?

You can set this at: `http://[site]/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend&reset=1`

The default setting for this is: `http://[site]/`

See [the Wiki](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location) for more details.

Comment: so my base URL should be http://[site]/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ or http://[site]/ ?

Comment: Sorry, it should be http://[site]/.  I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: yes that is what is set there